# Custom binding for POST data, choosing type based on value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I'm using Asp.NET MVC Core 2 to implement a REST WebAPI. In my controller, I have a method that accepts a `POST` request that looks like this:

```
[HttpPost("Configuration")]
public IActionResult Configuration([FromBody] BridgeConfiguration data)
{
    ...
}
```

This works, but the problem is that the `BridgeConfiguration` class that you see in the method signature is a base class, and what I would like to do is actually select an appropriate derived class for binding, based on one of the values in the incoming object.

I've read that this can be done using a custom model binder, but I'm having trouble implementing it. What I did is this: I changed the controller method to:

```
[HttpPost("Configuration")]
public IActionResult Configuration([ModelBinder(typeof(BridgeConfigurationModelBinder))] BridgeConfiguration data)
{
    ...
}
```

and tried to implement a model binder:

```
public class BridgeConfigurationModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var nameProp = bindingContext.ModelMetadata.Properties["name"]; //Exists and contains all the proper info :)
        var nameVal = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("name"); //Returns empty value :(

        //how do I get the value of the "name" field???

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that, as you can see from the comments, even if in the metadata the field I'm looking for is defined correctly, it's value is not. The `ValueProvider` always returns empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

If it's of any use, the body of my post request is something like this:

```
{
    name: "somename",
    foo: "bar",
    ...
}
```

Nothing weird, just a simple JSON.